# Calculating Optomechanical coupling rate

Tags: quantum-optics, quantum-measurements

How do I calculate the optomechanical coupling rate $G$ [Hz/m] through thermal motion? I measured the spectrum with a spectrum analyzer which was connected to a rf-source and the laser detector. I get my power spectral density out of that which is in V/sqrt(Hz). I can fit the resonance and get my transduction $dV/du$. Can I get from the transduction the optomechanical coupling rate $G$? In a [scintific paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.4231.pdf) (arxiv) I could find out that you can calculate through the frequency noise $S_{\omega \omega}(\Omega)$ the $G$. The problem is that I didnt do a homodyne spectroscopy. Is there a diffrent way to calculate that?

$$S_{x x}(\Omega)=
\frac{1}{m_{\mathrm{eff}}} \frac{2 \Gamma_{\mathrm{m}} k_{\mathrm{B}} T}{\left(\Omega^2-\Omega_{\mathrm{m}}^2\right)^2+\Gamma_{\mathrm{m}}^2 \Omega^2}
$$

$$
S_{\omega \omega}(\Omega)=G^2 S_{x x}(\Omega)
$$

$m_{\mathrm{eff}}$ effective mass of the resonator,$\Gamma_{\mathrm{m}}$ damping of the mechanical oscillator,
$k_{\mathrm{B}}$ Boltzmann constant,
$T$ temperature,
$\Omega$ mechanical frequency,
$\Omega_{\mathrm{m}}$ mechanical resonance